# Adding 1-N records using subgrid in dynamic 365 CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, subgrid

Dear all I am new to Dynamic 365 CRM.

- I have a customer entity and customer form.
- I have another entity `customer_Order`, in which I have customer orders.

I want to show customer orders on customer forms. How do I achieve that?

Below are the details on what I did:
I have created another entity `Customer Order`, and in that entity I added "1-N" relationship with `customer` table. I put a sub-grid, and I customized my form as well. I did not add any field on customer entity, nor did I add any relationship there.
My sub grid is appearing, but not showing add new button.

Comment: Hi Ahmed,
Upon creating 1:N relationship between Customer and Customer Order, system auto creates a lookup field to Customer in Customer Order entity.
You must be able to see '+' button next to Customer Orders subgrid on Customer form. Does your login account have sufficient permission to add records? Can you try with admin account?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to update the user security role by granting him the below permissions :
1- Create on Customer order entity
2- Append and Append to on Account entity